# NuGet version conflict issue on CodeAnalysis.Common when trying to use a Source Generator

Tags: .net, nuget, code-analysis, sourcegenerators

I have a .NET 6 MVC app, and a class library.

In the class library, I wanted to use a source generator.

I added the NuGet package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` to my class library

However I get this error:

> Version conflict detected for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common.
> Install/reference Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 4.3.0 directly to
> project MyMVCApp to resolve this issue.   
> MyMVCApp -> MyClassLibrary
> -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 4.3.0 -> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (= 4.3.0) 
>   MyMVCApp ->
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design 6.0.7 ->
> Microsoft.DotNet.Scaffolding.Shared 6.0.7 ->
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features 4.0.0 ->
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common (=
> 4.0.0).   MyMVCApp    C:\x\MyMVCApp.csproj    1

I can't see a way to resolve this, confused why there's a hard coded requirement for version 4 or why it can't work around it. Any ideas? I'm not au fait with diagnosing this type of issue.

I should add, I tried doing what it said but it just gave me the conflict message and said "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes".

Comment: If you see "Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes", the chances are that your build failed, with a failing build it won't let you install packages.
Best is to fix the build; then you can install the NuGet package (in this case "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common 4.3.0").